# Laravel Not Found Http Exception in Route Collection hp line 179

Tags: php, laravel

Please, i am a novice in Laravel, i am running Laravel 5.4.21.

I was following a tutorial on creating a todo list application which is basically crud and the tutor was making use of resource-based routes.

I have been trying for 2 days to resolve this error on my own.

I will be grateful if anyone can assist me in sorting this issue out.

My controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Todo;

class TodosController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
       $todos = Todo::orderBy('created_at','desc')->get();
       return view('todo.index')->with('todos', $todos);
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
        $todo = Todo::find($id);
        return view('todo.show')->with('todo', $todo);
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

This is my index page

```
@extends('layout.app')

@section('content')
  <div class="col-lg-12 mt-2 mb-2">
    <p class="bg-success text-white font-weight-bold text-center pt-2 pb-2">
      RECENT TASKS
    </p>
  </div>

  @if(count($todos) >0)
    @foreach($todos as $todo)
      <div class="card bg-primary text-dark p-2">
        <h4 class="text-white"><a class="text-white" href="todo/{{$todo->id}}">{{ $todo->text }}</a><br><span class="badge badge-danger text-left" style="font-size: 14px;">{{ $todo->due }}</span></h3>
      </div><br>
    @endforeach
  @endif
@endsection
```

This is my routes.

```
<?php

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/


Route::get('/', 'TodosController@index');

Route::resource('Todo','TodosController');
```

Comment: please post also the error and tell whaen that error occurs

Comment: Add the errors message

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without any other informations about the error and when it occurs, i can't figure out exactly why you are getting an error, but i can see those things that can cause an error (the last one is just a tips):

1. `Route::resource('Todo','TodosController');` should be `Route::resource('todo','TodosController');`, because the routes are case sensitive
2. the `href` on your `<a>` is relative, instead of absolute, so it will append that route to the current path, instead of going straight there, so change `<a class="text-white" href="todo/{{$todo->id}}">` to `<a class="text-white" href="/todo/{{$todo->id}}">`
3. Also, just to let you know about it, Laravel `Route::resource` make use of route name, so instead of write the path, you should use the `route()` function in this way `<a class="text-white" href="{{route('todo.show',$todo->id)}}">`

Comment: Based on your first suggestion all I had to do was to was change

Route::resource('Todo','TodosController'); 

To

should be Route::resource('todo','TodosController');

Thank you bro, I really appreciate your help.

Comment: no problem, but i would recommend also to take in account the second one, because in other page that wouldn't be the homepage, it will cause issue